# How to edit embed with message id discord bot py in on_ready event

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to edit a embed in on_ready event this is the only way i can edit can do on_message or is there a way to keep a function running until the program ends?

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    msg = bot.get_message(892788147287654471)
    em = discord.Embed(title="lik",description="kjk")
    await msg.edit(embed=em)

bot.run(os.environ['token'])
```

error code:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 56, in on_ready
    msg = bot.get_message(892788147287654471)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_message'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as the error says, bot has no `get_message` attribute. Instead what you can do is get the channel, and then get the message or partial message within.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=partial%20message#discord.PartialMessage

Example:

```py
message = bot.get_channel(1234567890).get_partial_message(1234567890)
await message.edit(content="test")
```

Comment: thanks....ill check it out

Comment: It works perfectly.